# Graph Theory - Introduction Questions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

I have a couple of questions that are probably SUPER easy for anybody that has studied graph theory but are confusing the hell out of me. I know it may be inconvenient to help me but I have a test coming up and I'm really confused.

**Question 1: If there are 2 vertices that have the same neighborhood, then which statement must hold?**

1) Both vertices will be of deg zero?

2) The deg of every vertex will be even?

3) There is an edge between the two vertices?

4) There cannot be an edge between the two vertices?

I thought that it was #3 but it wasn't.

**Question 2:** 
Consider a graph G with vertices {v1, v2, v3, v4} and edges {(v1,v2), (v2,v3), (v1,v3), (v2,v4)}
What is the degree of v3?

1) 2

2) 4

3) 3

4) 1

**Question 3:**
G = ({v1, v2, v3, v4, v5}, {(v1,v2), (v2,v3),(v3,v4), (v4,v5),(v5,v1),(v2,v4),(v2,v5)})
Which of the following is NOT a subgraph of G?

1) G' = ({v1, v2, v3, v4, v5}, {(v1,v2), (v2,v3),(v3,v4), (v4,v5),(v5,v1)})

2) G' = ({v1, v3, v4, v5}, {(v3,v4), (v4,v5),(v5,v1), (v2,v4)})

3) G' = ({v1, v2, v3, v4, v5}, {(v1,v2)})

4) G' = ({v2, v4, v5}, {(v4,v5),(v2,v4),(v2,v5)})

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see why you think it is an invalid question and contains erros, so I rolled it back. Please explain why you think that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

- Question 1: Note that the neighbourhood of a vertex is the set of
  vertices that are connected to it plus all the edges that connect those vertices among themselves. A vertex does not belong to its own neighbourhood. If there is an edge between
  two vertices then they are definitely in the neighbourhood of each other. What would that imply?
- Question 2: What's the degree of a graph? You just have to count.
- Question 3: A subgraph is formed by a subset of the original vertex set plus all the edges that connect those vertices *amongst themselves*. Alternative 2) has an edge that, even though it belongs to the original graph, does not connect the selected vertices of the subgraph.

Comment: If there are 2 vertices and they are in the same neighborhood based on what you just wrote that should imply that they have an edge between them but that answer was marked as wrong.

Comment: If they did have an edge in common, they would have different neighbourhoods, since they don't belong to their own neighbourhoods, so they must *not* have an edge in common. If you call the vertices $u$ and $v$, if they had an edge in common then it would follow that $v \in nbhd(u)$ but $v \not \in nbdh(v)$.

Comment: Alright looks like I got Q1 and Q2 right. However Q3 stumps me. If I'm not mistaken 1 and 3 aren't bigger than their parent they are the same size right? I think the answer is #2 because it shows 4 vertices but it has an edge between v2 and v4 however v2 is not part of the new subgraph. So I'm assuming answer #2 is the right answer because it wouldn't be a subgraph of G?

Comment: Maybe you have made a typo? From what you wrote G has 4 vertices whereas some alternatives have 5.

Comment: Yup, typo, looks like the whole graph for #3 that I wrote down was a replica from question 2. I just updated it.

Comment: In that case you're right, 2) is the right answer since $v_2 v_4$ is not part of the subgraph. I will update my answer.